# Sharepoint Online: How to embed a PDF document

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf

How can I upload and embed a PDF document in a single column web-part, in Sharepoint Online? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ***Page Viewer*** webpart in SharePoint Online for this purpose.

**Steps:**

1. Upload the PDF document in any library and copy its URL.
2. In your SharePoint page, add a Page viewer webpart as *Media and Content > Page Viewer*
3. Edit the webpart and add the copied link in Step 1.

Now you will be able to view the embedded PDF as shown below.

[image]

There is a different method as well that uses the *embed* tag.

1. In your page, add a content editor webpart
2. Add the below code to embed the PDF

   ```
   <object>
       <embed type="application/pdf" src="thesamePDFlocation.PDF" ></embed>
   </object>
   ```

Comment: I didn't like the Page Viewer web part, as it gave options for people to download the PDF. I wanted people to view it only, as if it were an image, so I did the embed tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can - use "[File viewer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-file-viewer-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c)" web part. Here are two good articles  ( [first](http://darcehessllc.com/the-file-viewer-web-part-get-the-most-out-of-the-modern-out-of-the-box-web-parts-series/) and [second](https://tracyvanderschyff.com/2018/01/09/sharepoint-online-web-parts-file-viewers/) ) on how to use and configure it.

[image: File viewer web part]